# Date format in JAVA

Tags: java

I  want to print April as APR IN JAVA WHERE 4 comes as parameter to indicate April. what can i do?i tried the format 'MMM' but it prints 'Apr' in stead of 'APR'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [String.toUpperCase()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29) method.

Answer (score 4):

why not just upper case your 'MMM' result ?

Answer (score 1):

With the `SimpleDateFormat` class you cannot or use `String.toUpperCase()` (as said Ben J) in conjunction with the "MMM".

This makes sense if you work with dates but if you just work with numbers (ie: 4) you can build a complete switch statement on the number...

Comment: I would recommend against the switch statement solution unless you are absolutely, positively, 100% certain that you will *never* **ever** have to cope with other languages in your app.  And even then recommend against the switch solution.  `String.toUpperCase()` is the right way to go.

Comment: Agree with you...  
The switch solution is a dirty solution but it's working ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use String.subString and then apply String.toUpperCase to get desired result.